# How to create a transparent JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make my JPanel transparent but i just can not achive that . I have tried this code, but it doesn't work. Also, what are the bound of the 'a' from rgba ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;


public class Animation extends JPanel implements Runnable
    JButton buton = new JButton("BUTTON!!!! ");


    public Animation(){
        add(buton);

    }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
            g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            super.paintComponent(g);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new Animation();
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(52, 152, 219,0));
        panel.repaint();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ;
```

Comment: Bounds for the alpha channel (the "a") are generally 0.0 through 1.0, where 1.0 is opaque. Think of it as a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this..

```
frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); //
```

//add to the code

```
   frame.setUndecorated(true);
   frame.setOpacity(0.5f);
```

*you can use the same for JFrame: actually is sets the trasparent color to panel or frame.The frame has to be Undecorated(true) first.*

You can set it also setting **alpha** to 0.

And here is [the magic  by oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: i had the same problem some months before and when i found the page i show you it was just the solution for many  other problems like to create windows with shape....!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `JPanel` is transparent but you are seeing the `JFrame`.

   You need to make it transparent too. (`JFrame` requires `frame.setUndecorated(true);` to be called first).

---

2. The bounds of alpha depend on the constructor of the `Color` that you are using.

   There are many overloaded constructors available. The one you are using expects an `int` and its bounds are 0-255.

   The constructor with `float` arguments requires bounds 0f to 1.0f.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.